# building qtwebkit5.7.1 for intel baytrail board

Tags: qt, yocto, qt5.7

i am trying to build `qtwebkit5.7.1` using yocto poky ...on `intel platform`.
but getting below errors.

```
| rm -f libQt5WebKit.so.5.7.0 libQt5WebKit.so libQt5WebKit.so.5 libQt5WebKit.so.5.7
| linking ../lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.7.0
| /home/pase/Projects/intel_poky_rel/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/qtwebkit/5.7.1+gitAUTOINC+76e2732f01-r0/build/Source/WebCore//.obj/platform/leveldb/LevelDBDatabase.o: In function `WebCore::LevelDBDatabase::openInMemory(WebCore::LevelDBComparator const*)':
| LevelDBDatabase.cpp:(.text._ZN7WebCore15LevelDBDatabase12openInMemoryEPKNS_17LevelDBComparatorE+0x3a): undefined reference to `leveldb::NewMemEnv(leveldb::Env*)'
| collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
| make[2]: *** [../lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5.7.0] Error 1
| make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/pase/Projects/intel_poky_rel/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/qtwebkit/5.7.1+gitAUTOINC+76e2732f01-r0/build/Source'
| make[1]: *** [sub-api-pri-make_first-ordered] Error 2
| make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/pase/Projects/intel_poky_rel/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/qtwebkit/5.7.1+gitAUTOINC+76e2732f01-r0/build/Source'
| make: *** [sub-Source-QtWebKit-pro-make_first-ordered] Error 2
```

can someone help me?

Comment: It seems to be a [Qt Bug](https://bugs.freebsd.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=212859)

Comment: taking my time to build qtwebkit and see if I get the same error.  So far I got into opengl error instead of what you have.  using intel-core2-32 as machine and Morty branch.